# Creating a mandala - Why is my ellipse not aligned perfectly symmetrically with guides

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

A bit puzzled today, I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHQi0I6dwmg) on creating a Mandala in Illustrator which uses the principles of locked layers and Transform Copies, it's been generally working great, however I notice some strange misalignments and I am unable to achieve 100% mathematical accuracy.

The ellipse is not sliced on an angle perfectly on the right like it is on the left. The ellipse is aligned horizontally and the Align To is set to Artboard.

Any ideas what's going on here?

[image]

This then starts to create a bigger knock on effect as it transforms around the guides.
[image]

My angle is 60° and my Copies is 5 as corresponding in the video.
[image]

Comment: have you checked the Align to pixels / Align to grid View options? are they active?

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without having access to the document. Could it be related to stroke width?

Comment: I don't know if it is the case, but Illustrator traditionally was not very exact when snaping objects.

Comment: Is your rotation pivot directly in the center?

Answer (score 0):

A 1 or 2 pt difference in the guide placement *will* show variation compared to the Effect.

The Effect, being automated and based upon the artwork bounds, is **accurate**, your *guides* are inaccurate or fail to take in the *bounds* of the artwork - meaning the paths **without** a stroke *may* meet your guides. However, the effect uses the **preview bounds** of objects, not spines. So a 1pt stroke means the effect is adding 1/2pt to either side of the artwork therefore changing final placement of copies.

You *might* try constructing the skeleton in **Outine Mode** (View > Outline Mode) *without* any appearance attributes (fills/strokes) applied to the actual paths. You may find the skeleton construction is more accurate this way.

Comment: either i dont get it or its just plain wrong somehow. Cant decide

Comment: @joojaa the guides may be constructed based on absolutes of spines. But the effect uses the relative bounds on the preview image. It's also not impossible that the guides themselves are positions a point or two off. Or the object alignment with the center rotation point is 1 or 2 pts off. Basically the Effect is always accurate in it's math, was my point.